# Interface implementation enforcement in Go

Tags: go, interface

I have simple Go code:

```golang
type MyInterface interface {
    Do()
}

type Doer struct{}

func (d *Doer) Do() {}

// Option 1
var _ MyInterface = (*Doer)(nil)

// Option 2
var _ MyInterface = &Doer{}
```

What is the downside of enforcing the interface with option 1 (which is widely used and advised everywhere) as opposed to option 2?

If we are discarding the result, what's the harm of instantiating a real object instead of pointer?

I understand that Option 2 is probably one millisecond slower as it does allocation of memory for the struct and also there is another millisecond for GC to clean it up probably, but all of it is happening only at startup and does not affect the runtime.

Are those my correct or do I miss anything?

Comment: This is a compile-time enforcement check - so don't overthink it and go with option 1 as it has zero runtime impact.

Comment: They both are valid `MyInterface` values, but the two aren't the same.  `(*Doer)(nil)` is a nil pointer to a Doer.  `&Doer{} is` a pointer to allocated memory.   Typically real life structrues have members that need to be initialized, so a nil pointer isn't appropriate in those cases.

Comment: Side note: Go naming conventions use `x-er` as the name of the *interface*, so `Doer` would be the name of an interface with a `Do` function, the way `Reader` is the name of the bytes and strings readers that have `Read` functions. The actual concrete implementation with some struct might be a `struct X` that *conforms to* the Doer implementation if there's a `Do` for it.

Comment: `what's the harm of instantiating a real object instead of pointer?` very little, if not none. It is only a package level variable. You can trust the Go team to have considered that and took the most approrpriate actions. Finally, in the doubt, if you find this practice within the code of the core language, then, you can reproduce safely even if you dont understand all the intricacies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analysis in the question is good. Here are two additional points:

Option 1 works with any type. Option 2 only works for types with composite literal syntax.

Here's an example:

```
type IntDoer int

func (d *IntDoer) Do() {}

// Option 1
var _ MyInterface = (*IntDoer)(nil)

// Option 2 DOES NOT COMPILE
var _ MyInterface = &IntDoer{}
```

Option 2 may not have any runtime penalty. It's possible that the compiler optimizes out the allocation.

Comment: I see. In this case I can use `var _ MyInterface = new(Doer)` that can handle both cases.